# Are two distance regular graphs with the same intersection array also cospectral for their Laplacian matrices?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

So we know that two DRGs with the same intersection array must be co-spectral on their adjacency matrices, i.e. their adjacency matrices have the same set of eigenvalues.

But is this necessarily true also for Laplacian matrices? Over here, the Laplacian matrix is defined as $L(G)=D(G)-A(G)$, where $D(G)$ and $A(G)$ represent the degree matrix and adjacency matrix, respectively.

Other than the Laplacian, what about the other matrices, such as the signless Laplacian matrix $|{L}|(G)=D(G)+A(G)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, distance-regular graphs with the same intersection array are in particular $k$-regular graphs with the same degree $k$. So for each graph, the Laplacian matrix $L(G)$ is just $kI - A(G)$. If the adjacency matrix has eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_n$, then the Laplacian matrix has eigenvalues $k - \lambda_1, \dots, k - \lambda_n$.

Therefore, the two graphs must also be co-spectral with respect to their Laplacian matrices, and (by the same argument) with respect to their signless Laplacian matrices.

Comment: Thanks, Misha. I have a follow-up question: how shall we distinguish two DRGs with the same intersection array? I found a paper, in which the results imply that such two DRGs are cospectral with almost all matrices (Laplacian, signless Laplacian, and many others)... Is there a tactics so that we can distinguish them based upon their algebraic structures? Or could you recommend some references if you know any? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: I don't know of anything that works generally and, as a matter of fact, highly symmetric graphs are often tough cases for graph isomorphism problems. Sorry :(

Comment: No problem, thanks! :)